# 400 No required SSL certificate was sent

Tags: c#, ssl, nginx, https

Can't send https request from C# client. Here is my code:

```
var client = WebRequest.Create("https://hastname.com/bla bla bla") as HttpWebRequest;
var cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\certs\\MyCert.pfx"), "MyPassword");
client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
result = new StreamReader(client.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Server side is ok, because if i'm intall cert in my mashine cert store, everythink is ok.

I'm compare 2 requests : 
1. Cert removed from cert store and i'm load it from file in code
2. Cert installed in cert store

**Below my results:**

**First, i'm load cert from file**

```
Secure Protocol: Tls
Cipher: Aes256 256bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha1 160bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=xxx, OU=Web Services, O=xxx, S=England, C=GB

[Issuer]
  E=xx@xxx.com, CN=xxx Server Intermediate CA, OU=CA, O=xxx, S=England, C=GB

[Serial Number]
  1000

[Not Before]
  17.09.2015 12:51:29

[Not After]
  26.09.2016 12:51:29

[Thumbprint]
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7
```

**And this, then i'm load cert from local mashine cert store**

```
Secure Protocol: Tls
Cipher: Aes256 256bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha1 160bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits

== Client Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=WinClient, OU=Client Apps, O=xxx, S=England, C=GB

[Issuer]
  E=xx@xxxxx.com, CN=xxxx Client Intermediate CA, OU=CA, O=xxx, S=England, C=GB

[Serial Number]
  1000

[Not Before]
  17.09.2015 13:19:55

[Not After]
  26.09.2016 13:19:55

[Thumbprint]
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7


== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=xx.xxxxxxx.com, OU=Web Services, O=xxx, S=England, C=GB

[Issuer]
  E=xx@xxxxx.com, CN=xxx Server Intermediate CA, OU=CA, O=xxx, S=England, C=GB

[Serial Number]
  1000

[Not Before]
  17.09.2015 12:51:29

[Not After]
  26.09.2016 12:51:29

[Thumbprint]
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7
```

As you can see, no client cert section in first request. How i can resolve my problem?

p.s. My point is send request with cert loaded from file, no from cert store.

Answer (score 0):

ok first of all there are some known issues with creating an X509Certificate2 object from a byte array, see tip 5 here http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2 for more info.

.pfx files can contain multiple certificates so you need to either load it and iterate through to find the one you want or just add them all. Try this code

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import("c:\\certs\\MyCert.pfx", "MyPassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
client.ClientCertificates.AddRange(collection);
```

Comment: Hi Kev. Thanks for your reply. But it's not work for me.